# Can't figure out why Ruby isn't cooperating

Tags: ruby

```
puts "Please Enter a text string: "
user_input = gets.chomp
puts "What word(s) would you like to redact?"
user_redacted = gets.chomp

user_input_words = user_input.split(" ")
user_redacted_words = user_redacted.split(" ")

user_input_words.each do |user_input_word|
    if user_input_word == user_redacted_words
        print "REDACTED "
    else
        print user_input_word + " "
    end
end
```

The code won't print redacted on the words that the user has chosen to redact. But it'll print out the user_input_words in plain text and not in ["an" "array"] format. Wouldn't the `user_input_word` array be matching the `user_redacted_words` array, to find the words that should be REDACTED?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: `user_input_word` in the block is a `String` while `user_redacted_words` is an `Array`, they'll never be equal. What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: Ah, so I was trying to compare a string to an array. Instead of just one word to redact, I was trying to get multiple words to redact. I thought my `user_redacted_words = user_redacted.split(" ")` would change the redacted string to an array?

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: Sorry about that, was too busy thinking about the problem, I had forgotten to insert the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want to check if the current word is contained in the list of redacted words. So instead of checking if one word is equal to an array of words:

```
if user_input_word == user_redacted_words
```

You want to instead check if that word is included in the array of redacted words:

```
if user_redacted_words.include? user_input_word
```

Comment: Oh my gosh, that worked! I haven't practiced the ".include?" thing much. Still learning Ruby. Could you please enlighten me as to why my == didn't/wouldn't work? (Just to get the understanding.)

Comment: Sure! So `user_input_word` will be one word they typed at the first input, say 'toast'. `user_redacted_words` will be an array of words (a list of words) created from what they entered at the second input, perhaps `['bananas', 'toast', 'pineapples']`. Now clearly, `'toast'` does not equal `['bananas', 'toast', 'pineapples']`, so when you use `==` to compare them, it will never be true. However, `'toast'` is included in `['bananas', 'toast', 'pineapples']`, so when you use the `include?` method, it will return true if the word is in the array of redacted words.

Comment: You can read about the [`include?` method in the docs.](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Array.html#method-i-include-3F). It takes one argument and returns true if the argument is in the array and false if the argument is not in the array.